# Highlight current site in the navigation drawer on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-experience

I observed something that appears to be anti UX design to me in the Android app.

In the navigation drawer after selecting a website, it is not highlighting the selected website, in the drawer when we reopen it.

Comment: Well, I would prefer for it to have the behavior as the web, which is showing the current site on top, with a link to its meta site.

Comment: Are these two separate platform

Comment: Yes, in the web sites top bar, we have the StackExchange button, when opened, the first things on top are the current site we're in and its meta site.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in its current writing, as it's never been implemented before. Retagged this as [tag:feature-request].